# how to return kendoDropDownList in jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I had a code like below

```
let ctrlClassificationLevel = $('#ctrlClassificationLevel').kendoDropDownList();
ctrlClassificationLevel.kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: data,//data coming from db
    //optionLabel: "User Type",
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
});
```

now I am trying to create a common code to for kendo dropdownlist as I have multiple Kendo dropdown in my application.

I changed the code to something like below

```
function BindKendoDropDownListWOCV(kendoDropDownId, textField, valueField, data, optionLabel, filter, suggest, index, value, changeFunction) {
    return kendoDropDownId.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: textField,
        dataValueField: valueField,
        dataSource: data,
        optionLabel: optionLabel,
        filter, filter,
        suggest: suggest,
        index: index,
    });
}

ctrlClassificationLevel = BindKendoDropDownListWOCV(ctrlClassificationLevel, 'Name', 'Id', data, null, 'contains', true, null, null, undefined);
```

but now when I click on some value of my Kendo DropDownList I get the error ->  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Name')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your return statement, you should return the instance of the DropDownList rather than the result of the kendoDropDownList method.

And when you pass the `kendoDropDownId` argument, presumably since the name implies it should just be the id, then only pass the string and then get the DOM in the function.

Here is an example:

```js
const BindKendoDropDownListWOCV = (kendoDropDownId, textField, valueField, data, optionLabel, filter, suggest, index, value, changeFunction) => {
    const element = $(kendoDropDownId);
    if (!element) {
        console.error(`Unable to find the DOM by selector: ${kendoDropDownId}`);
        return null;
    }
    return element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: textField,
        dataValueField: valueField,
        dataSource: data,
        optionLabel: optionLabel,
        filter, filter,
        suggest: suggest,
        index: index,
    }).data('kendoDropDownList');
}
let ctrlClassificationLevel = BindKendoDropDownListWOCV('#ctrlClassificationLevel', 'Name', 'Id', data, null, 'contains', true, null, null, undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a reference to that newly created DropDownList and return that reference - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/uledutUh)